# How to ignore DST adjustments made by java while retrieving date column from an Oracle database?

Tags: java, oracle, datetime, jdbc, timezone

I have an Oracle table with **Date** column in it.

```
+--------+-----------------------+
|  ID    | CURR_DATE             |       
+--------+-----------------------+                       
|   1    |2003-04-06 02:59:59    |
+--------+-----------------------+
```

When I do a

```
select * from tablename
```

in the database console, I get the correct column value for CURR_DATE.

But when I do the same from a java program using JDBC, the time shifts one hour forward due to daylight saving. Here is a link that explains it. https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york?year=2003.

So I receive the value 2003-04-06 **03:59:59** instead of 2003-04-06 **02:59:59**.

This happens because the DB and the JVM are in PST and PST follows DST.(Pls correct me if I am wrong)

Here is my code

```
String query="select * from tablename";         
PreparedStatement psmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet results=psmt.executeQuery();
while(results.next()) {
    System.out.println(results.getString(2));
}
```

What can be done so that `results.getString()` returns me the same value which is in the database(without any adjustments).

I want it to return me the original value 2003-04-06 **02:59:59** instead of the adjusted value 2003-04-06 **03:59:59**.

Comment: Why not work on UTC and manage DST in your code?

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj Some more explanation could be helpful. Why not help with an answer? I do not have much idea about these timezone jargons.

Comment: Perhaps try `results.getObject(2, LocalDateTime.class)`

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj Neither UTC or DST matters, as the Oracle `DATE` type holds only a date and a time-of-day without any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

Answer (score 2):

As @gord-thompson explained you should use an up to date ojdbc8 or ojdbc10, ideally 19.3 or 18.3, you can use these even if your database is 11.2g https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_02

```
results.getObject(2, LocalDateTime.class)
```

**Explanation**

The issue is really with the implementation of the `java.sql.Timestamp` class. It represents the milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT and 2003-04-06 02:59:59 **in JVM time zone**, 2003-04-06 02:59:59 does not exist in JVM time zone so the parser is off by the DST change.

`LocalDateTime` is not bound to any time zone and just year-month-day-hour-minute-second-nano and therefore has no issues representing 2003-04-06 02:59:59 whatever the JVM time zone.

Comment: Tried your and Gord's approach using ojdbc8. got the following exception   -  Method oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleResultSetImpl.getObject(ILjava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; is abstract

Comment: You're not using ojdbc8 or ojdbc10

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

## Use smart objects, not dumb strings

You storing a date-time value in a date-time column, so use a date-time type in Java. Currently your are using strings.

The Oracle [`DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1837) type holds only a date and a time-of-day without any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. As such, a `DATE` column cannot be used to represent a moment. The equivalent in standard SQL is `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

For example, if a row stores a value in that column for the 23rd of January of this year at noon, we have know way to know if this is noon in Tokyo, noon in Kolkata, noon in Paris, or noon in Montréal. These various noons all occur in different moments, hours apart.

The appropriate type in Java to match an Oracle `DATE` column is `LocalDateTime`. This class also lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So it cannot be used to represent a moment. But when you have only a date and time-of-day without zone/offset, this is the class for you.

JDBC 4.2 and later requires support for directly exchanging *java.time* objects with the database.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

Writing data.

```
myPreparedStatemen.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

By exchanging a Java object without any zone/offset with a database column of a types without any zone/offset, **you will have no issue with zone/offset**. But be aware of the limitations of this kind of date-time value:

- Not a moment, not a point on the timeline.
- Ambiguous as it could be interpreted as any of many *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours (the range of time zones around the globe).

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both modern and legacy) and in standard SQL.]

Comment: That diagram is wrong, JDBC maps `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` to `java.sql.Timestamp` or `java.time.LocalDateTime`, while `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` doesn't have a corresponding legacy type. And JDBC does not provide support for `Instant` nor `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: I believe the table says part of that: ´Instant´ and `ZonedDateTime` aren't supported by JDBC because the purple "JDBC 4.2" bar is missing.